# How can I stream video from my webcam with sound from my microphone using vlc?

Tags: vlc, webcam, microphone, streaming, video-streaming

I can stream video from my webcam using 
`vlc v4l2:// :v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=256}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=:1234}" -I dummy`,
 but how can I add the sound from my microphone to the streaming video?

Answer (score 1):

`cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard=ALL :input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0 :live-caching=300  ':sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=3500,width=1920,height=1080,acodec=mp3,ab=192,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ts,dst=:8080/}'`

Comment: can you explain what this does?